# Store the name of a function into a variable

Tags: linux, bash

I've been trying to store the name of a function into a variable, but just the name.

```
doReturn() {

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        /bin/echo -e " \e[1;31mOk!\e[0m"
    else
        /bin/echo -e " \e[1;31mFAIL!\e[0m"
        $? = fail
        echo $fail

        exit 1;
    fi
}
```

I'd like to get "doReturn" to make an if or something like that to  say: "the program ended here". I don't know if I'm playing to be God or something

I've tried  with a sed and $?, but nothing

```
doReturn() {

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        /bin/echo -e " \e[1;31mOk!\e[0m"
    else
        /bin/echo -e " \e[1;31mFAIL!\e[0m"
        $? = fail
        echo $fail

        exit 1;
    fi
}
```

I didn't get anything trying with the sed. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: You can't assign to `$?`

Comment: Nope, maybe i'm not doing it right. Eitherway, `$?` just captures the error right?

Comment: The equivalent of setting `$?` would be to simply run a command with a known exit value. Running `false`, for example, would set `$?` to 1`. In general, run `exit` from inside a sub shell. `(exit 57)` would set `$?` to 57.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man bash` :

> The first element of the FUNCNAME variable is set to the name of the function while the function is executing.

So if portability doesn't matter you can use `${FUNCNAME[0]}`

Comment: But `${FUNCNAME[0]}` you have to tell the position or it would capture it?

Comment: `${FUNCNAME[0]}` is automatically set as you enter functions and popped off the `FUNCNAME` array as you return from them. You can set your variable to that value as long as you do it from inside the function whose name you want to capture.

Comment: Thats the problem. From a function I call another function which is gonna tell me if there was any problem, in case there was a problem, that child-function has to record the father-function name and the error. The error is not a problem, cus `$?` captures it, but the problem is on the function's name

Comment: You can probably use `${FUNCNAME[1]}` if it's the name of the function that calls your error-detecting function that is relevant

Comment: Gonna check it out. Thanks <3

Comment: I appreciate that Aaron, it's working fine! Thank you